# ng flow is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, flow-js

Hi Guys I am using ng flow in my visual studio web project. I copied all the ng flow javascript file from github.

I have initialised ng flow by using ng-init directive but whenever i am selecting file from my  file control i am getting $flow as undefined and therefore i cannot access $scope("flow:fileAdded") event and my files are always null.

my code is given below on how I am using it.

```
<div class="row">
                <div data-flow-init="" data-flow-file-added="!!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[$file.getExtension()]">
                    <!--<div data-ng-init="setFlow($flow)"></div>-->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ll">ll Compay</label>
                            <!--<span class="btn btn-default" data-flow-btn="">Upload File
                                <input type="file" multiple="multiple" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">
                            </span>-->
                           <span class="btn" flow-btn o>Upload File</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
```

above mentioned is my html then In my controller I have got

```
 $scope.AddB = function (fileData) {
          $scope.BFactory.Adll(fileData, $flow.files);
            }
```

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the $flow object in a parent scope (your $scope is a parent scope of the ng-flow directive's one) you have to use the flow-name attribute, as stated in the documentation: [docs](https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow#how-can-i-assign-flow-to-a-parent-scope)

Just make sure you define an object to hold the $flow instance, and you can use it after the container loads

HTML:

```
<div ng-init="divLoaded()" flow-init flow-name="obj.flow" ... > ... </div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.obj = {};
$scope.divLoaded = function() {
    // from now on, $scope.obj.flow will be defined
    console.log($scope.obj.flow);
}
```

Comment: Is this a common pattern?